# Difference in Object Representation in console (JavaScript V8) in different cases

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototypal-inheritance

**Case-I:** Representation of Object in console

```
var obj1 = {name: "Robert"}
console.log(obj1);
console.log(obj1.__proto__)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now, see the representation of object:

- There are a set of curly braces.
- Property-values inside the curly braces.
- Also, the name of object is "**Obj1**" but nowhere mentioned.

**case-II:** Object Representation in another case

```
var str = "abc";
console.log(str.__proto__);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Now, Notice:

- There is still an object with a set of property-values inside it.
- The difference is that now "String" text is now seen infront of Object.
- The question is if in earlier case we did not see "Obj1" or "Object" -- in case of proto of object or object constructor in earlier case, why Now???
- It should either be in none cases or "Obj1" or "Object" whould have been attached in case I too.
- Isn't all this wrong??????

**In Short:**

> Now, my problem is -- for what the hello is "String" --- keyword doing
>   here? If it was an object then --- only 2 curly braces should have
>   been there --- and properties inside it. From what new rule is this
>   "String" keyword displayed before the object? Isn't this ***wrong***
>   or ***anomaly***?

[image]

Comment: It's an implementation quirk, I don't think any of it has any *official* meaning, it's just what the engine developers decided to display to the user when things get logged

Comment: That's because the name to the left is not the name of the object but the class of the object. For example `x = "", console.log(x.__proto__)` should print `String`, not `x`. As a shorthand plain `Object` object are just represented by `{...` and `Array` objects are represented by `[...`. There's not real reason for this - just what the browser developer felt like doing

Comment: Yah, right, but then why not the same for if the constructor gets to "Object"? Or if we locally develop any object? -- same case, isn't it. This seems to be inconsistency or confusion --- as you'll get same for String, Number, Boolean. When it is case of object or its derivatives (array, function, etc.) there is no "Object" term which is wierd.

Comment: @slebetman: Yah, so lets have `x = {}`. Now, what should `console.log(x.__proto__)` now print? Not 'x' but "Object" atleast I expect man.

Comment: Like I said. You need to ask the browser developers why. There is no particularly concrete reason for it. The display of the class is mainly done to help debugging. There is nothing in the language spec defining how it should work. In fact, `console.log()` is not in the language spec so Chrome can (and indeed do) implement it differently from node.js or Edge or Firefox

Comment: They probably thought that `Object {}` is redundant because `{}` already represents an object.